# Microsoft Dynamics Web API | PATCH invoice detail

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, patch, webapi, dynamics-crm-webapi

Does anyone know how to update the invoice detail entity along with Invoice under postman? I have searched google but not find many useful answers for this. I even try to use odata.bind annotation but still not able to solve my issue here. Basically, I just want to update Invoice Details along with Invoice in one API call. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Postman SC for Patch InvoiceDetail]

Comment: no you cannot do that, you will need to perform patch on invoice_details

Comment: if you want to update 2 records you need two calls, you can eventually batch them but afaik you can't do in a single call

Answer (score 0):

We have a concept called deep insert for creating parent and child record in one call. Unfortunately for updating/patching we have to deal with one object at a time. ie invoice and invoice detail separately.